# How to change the value of a specific row of table by clicking on another value on the same row using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the last table value of a row by clicking on the **3rd** td value. However, when I click on the **3rd** td of any table row, it only changes the last td value of the first row.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.selectslots').change(function(){ 
    var myselectslots=$(this).val(); 
    var rowrate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text(); 
    $(this).attr('value', rowrate); console.log("clicked on the slot"); 
    console.log(rowrate); //The selectslots class is a class for the values of the third column. 

    $.ajax({
            url:'http://127.0.0.1/sufee/slotpurchase.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                        myselectslots:myselectslots},
                        success:function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                        console.log(myselectslots);

                    if (myselectslots==30){
                        $('tr td:eq(5)').html('90');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('tr td:eq(5)').html(80);

                    } 

                }
            });
      });
```

My expectation is: if I click on a value on a column of a particular row, the last value of that row should change. The problem is, for now, only the last value of the first row changes regardless on the row I clicked on. Please help.

Comment: Your selector is not specifying any particular row, show your event handler so we can see how best to do the selection.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.selectslots').change(function(){
        var myselectslots=$(this).val();
        var rowrate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text();
        $(this).attr('value', rowrate);
         console.log("clicked on the slot");
         console.log(rowrate);      //The selectslots class is a class for the values of the third column.

Comment: You should incorporate that in the question

Comment: Alright. Done. I have added the selector to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the row in a variable before the ajax call to use it in the success call back

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.selectslots').change(function(){ 
    var myselectslots=$(this).val(); 
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')
    var rowrate = row.find('td:last').text(); 
    $(this).attr('value', rowrate); console.log("clicked on the slot"); 


    $.ajax({
            url:'http://127.0.0.1/sufee/slotpurchase.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                        myselectslots:myselectslots},
                        success:function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                        console.log(myselectslots);

                    if (myselectslots==30){
                        row.find('td:eq(5)').html('90');
                    }
                    else{
                       row.find('td:eq(5)').html(80);

                    } 

                }
            });
      });
```